# Using multiple gMSA accounts for SQL Server authentication in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, authorization, impersonation, gmsa

I'm working on a project where I have a number of SQL Servers (think lab, acceptance, prod), and a number of databases running on each of them. My application will execute migrations on those databases, triggerable through a .NET API and accompanying web interface: the application will make the mapping (authorization) between the AD user requesting the migration, and the gMSA account that will be executing the migration, installed on the IIS webserver where my application runs.

Each database belongs to a project, and all databases' structure for a specific project can be modified by a gMSA account.

My question: how would you tackle impersonating these gMSA accounts? Remember that there are many: just configuring my IIS application to run as a particular gMSA user is not an option.

Some ideas I had myself:

- .NET impersonation: I can't find how this would work with gMSA accounts, some questions have been asked about it but they all have gone unanswered
- Running a powershell service for each gMSA account, which periodically checks and picks up new migration requests
- Running the API with a gMSA account, and give that one access to all databases on all servers.

The first one is my best-case scenario, two I won't attempt due to operational complexity. The third is my backup plan but obviously has some potential security risks (although an argument could be made that authorization is anyway the responsibility of my API).

Looking forward to your opinions.

Comment: A practical approach would be to implement a hybrid system that leverages Windows Services or Task Scheduler tasks. Each of these services or tasks can be configured to run under a specific gMSA account, corresponding to the database it needs to operate on. Your .NET API would act as a coordinator, invoking these services or tasks as needed based on the AD user's request and the associated database. This method balances security, by ensuring each gMSA account has limited and specific access, and maintainability, by centralizing control in the .NET API

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I was thinking to avoid creating services, as it would require the operator to manually create a new service for each new gMSA account, however that may not be true: perhaps I can create the services from the account that is running the API, and assign each of them to run with a different gMSA account. Do you think this is feasible? I'll definitely try it out. I also need to think about some method of communication, but that might be a json file in a service-specific directory that is checked by the service every so often.

Comment: It's technically feasible to programmatically create Windows services. This can be done through various methods, such as using PowerShell scripts or the Windows Service Control Manager API.  Using a JSON file in a service-specific directory is a straightforward and simple method for communication between your API and the individual services. Each service could periodically poll its designated directory for a new JSON file containing migration tasks. Hope that helps!